# vectorize two nested for-loops in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, for-loop, vectorization

I have two nested for-loops that are used to format data that I load it. The loops have the following construction:

```
data = magic(20000);
data = data(:,1:3);

for i=0:10
    for j=0:10
        data_tmp = data((1:100)+100*j+100*10*i,:);
        vx(:, i+1,j+1) = data_tmp(:,1);
        vy(:, i+1,j+1) = data_tmp(:,2);
        vz(:, i+1,j+1) = data_tmp(:,3);
    end
end
```

Arrays `vx`, `vy` and `vz` I do pre-allocate to their desired size. However, is there a way to vectorize the `for`-loops to increase the efficiency? I'm not convinced it is the case due to the first line in the second loop, `data((1:100)+100*j+100*10*i,:)`, is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that you have repeated index in loop

at `i=k, j=10` and `i=k+1, j=0` for `k<10`

for example, you read `1:100 + 100*10 + 100*10*0` and then read `1:100 + 100*0 + 100*10*1` which are identical.

## Reshape w/ Repeated index

If this was what you intended to do, then vectorization needs one more step (index generation).

Following is my suggestion (`N=100, M=10` where `N` is the length of `data_tmp` and `M` is the maximum loop variable)

```
index = bsxfun(@plus,bsxfun(@plus,(1:N)',reshape(N*(0:M),1,1,M+1)),M*N*(0:M)); %index generation
vx = data(index);
vy = data(index + size(data,1));
vz = data(index + size(data,1)*2);
```

This is not that desirable, but it will work.

When I tested on my laptop, it is twice faster than your original code with pre-allocation. As I increase the size of data, the gap gets smaller and smaller.

## Reshape w/o Repeated index

If not i.e., you want to reshape each column in the direction of 3rd dimension first, 2nd dimension last), then following would work.

Firstly, this is how I interpreted your code

```
data = magic(20000);
data = data(:,1:3);

N = 100; M = 10;
for i=0:(M-1)
    for j=0:(M-1)
        data_tmp = data((1:N)+M*j+N*M*i,:);
        vx(:, i+1,j+1) = data_tmp(:,1);
        vy(:, i+1,j+1) = data_tmp(:,2);
        vz(:, i+1,j+1) = data_tmp(:,3);
    end
end
```

**Note that loop ended at `(M-1)`.**

Following is my suggestion.

```
vx = permute(reshape(dat(1:N*M*M,1), N, M, M),[1,3,2]);
vy = permute(reshape(dat(1:N*M*M,2), N, M, M),[1,3,2]);
vz = permute(reshape(dat(1:N*M*M,3), N, M, M),[1,3,2]);
```

In my laptop, it is 4 times faster than original code. As I increase the size, the gap approaches to 2.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case you want to stick with the loop, here is a much faster way to do this:

```
data = randi(100,20000,3);
[vx,vy,vz] = deal(zeros(100,11,11));
[J,I] = ndgrid(1:11,1:11);
c = 1;
for k = 0:100:11000
    vx(:,I(c),J(c)) = data((1:100)+k,1);
    vy(:,I(c),J(c)) = data((1:100)+k,2);
    vz(:,I(c),J(c)) = data((1:100)+k,3);
    c = c+1;
end
```

My guess is that `reshape` from @Dohyun answer is what you looking for (and it's x10 faster than this, and x10000 faster than your code), but for next time you use loops, this may be useful.

---

And here is another option to do this without `reshape`, in a similar time to the `reshape` version:

```
[vx,vy,vz] = deal(zeros(100,10,11));
vx(:) = data(1:11000,1);
vy(:) = data(1:11000,2);
vz(:) = data(1:11000,3);
vx = permute(vx,[1 3 2]);
vy = permute(vy,[1 3 2]);
vz = permute(vz,[1 3 2]);
```

The idea is that you define the shape of `[vx,vy,vz]` while allocating them.